# How to reduce redundancy in supercollider code?su

Tags: audio, signal-processing, supercollider

## Greetings

---

**I wrote this piece in supercollider**
**The code is currently a bit messy and introduces some redundancy, although it does what I want it to do, just with more lines of code then needed, and thanks to some bruteforcing (repeating identical code structures, to revalidate, random options, which could certainly be fixed somehow)**

**how to improve the code semantics, and get this piece of code written with fewer lines of code?**

---

**I can currently:**

- *interpret and run the code*
- *listen to nonlinear results*
- *appreciate the piece being generated procedurally*
- *listen to the dynamic stochastic allocation of DSP patterns*

**I would like to:**

- *do the same with less code*
- *have more elegant code design*

```
// WIPSupercolliderPiece-v.0.0.41-IannixXenakisStyleSuperStruktureGenerator-TiagoMoraisMorgado2022
~meinServer = ServerOptions.new; ~meinServer.memSize = 4096*512; Server.local.reboot

(

//strukt1 A
~strukt1_1={Mix.fill(33,{[SinOsc, Saw, Pulse].choose.ar(freq:[rrand(33,2000),rrand(33,2000)]*XLine.kr(rrand(0.125,8),rrand(0.125,8),150,doneAction:2)) })*0.06};
~strukt1_2={Mix.fill(33,{[SinOsc, Saw, Pulse].choose.ar(freq:[rrand(666,2222),rrand(666,2222)]*XLine.kr(rrand(0.125,8),rrand(0.125,8),150,doneAction:2)) })*0.06};
~strukt1_3={Mix.fill(33,{[SinOsc, Saw, Pulse].choose.ar(freq:[rrand(666,2222),rrand(666,2222)]*XLine.kr(rrand(0.125,8),rrand(0.125,8),150,doneAction:2)) })*0.06};

//strukt1 B
~strukt1_4={Mix.fill(33,{[SinOsc, Saw, Pulse].choose.ar(freq:[rrand(33,2000),rrand(33,2000)]*XLine.kr(rrand(0.125,8),rrand(0.125,8),150,doneAction:2)*TRand.kr(rrand(0.125,4),rrand(0.125,4),Impulse.kr(1/10)) )*0.06})};
~strukt1_5={Mix.fill(33,{[SinOsc, Saw, Pulse].choose.ar(freq:[rrand(666,2222),rrand(666,2222)]*XLine.kr(rrand(0.125,8),rrand(0.125,8),150,doneAction:2))*TRand.kr(rrand(0.125,4),rrand(0.125,4),Impulse.kr(1/10)) })*0.06};
~strukt1_6={Mix.fill(33,{[SinOsc, Saw, Pulse].choose.ar(freq:[rrand(666,2222),rrand(666,2222)]*XLine.kr(rrand(0.125,8),rrand(0.125,8),150,doneAction:2))*TRand.kr(rrand(0.125,4),rrand(0.125,4),Impulse.kr(1/10)) })*0.06};

//strukt2
~strukt2_1={Mix.fill(33,{FreeVerb.ar([SinOsc, Saw, Pulse].choose.ar(freq:[rrand(33,2000),rrand(33,2000)] * TRand.kr(0.125,4,Impulse.kr(1/10)),mul:EnvGen.kr(Env.perc,Impulse.kr(1/2 * TRand.kr(0.125,4,Impulse.kr(1/5)))*XLine.kr(rrand(0.125,4),rrand(0.125,4),159,doneAction:2)) ))})*0.3};
~strukt2_2={Mix.fill(33,{FreeVerb.ar([SinOsc, Saw, Pulse].choose.ar(freq:[rrand(33,2000),rrand(33,2000)],mul:[0.3,0.3]) )})};

//strukt3
~strukt3={GVerb.ar([SinOsc, Saw, Pulse].choose.ar(freq:322,mul:Blip.ar(rrand(1,30)*TRand.kr(0.125,4,Impulse.kr([1/4,1/7]))*XLine.kr(rrand(0.125,4),rrand(0.125,4),150,doneAction:2))),revtime:0.3)*3};

//strukt4
~strukt4_1_1={GVerb.ar(WhiteNoise.ar(mul:Blip.ar(rrand(1,30)*TRand.kr(0.125,4,Impulse.kr([1/4,1/7]))*XLine.kr(rrand(0.125,4),rrand(0.125,4),159,doneAction:2))),revtime:0.3)*3};
~strukt4_1_2={GVerb.ar(WhiteNoise.ar(mul:ChaosGen.allSubclasses.choose.ar([rrand(1,30),rrand(1,30)]),revtime:0.3)*3)};

//strukt5
~strukt4_2_1={Mix.fill(33,{([Saw,Pulse,SinOsc].choose.ar(freq:[LFDNoise0,LFDNoise1,LFDNoise3].choose.kr(1,505,322)+666*XLine.kr(rrand(0.125,8),rrand(0.125,8),150,doneAction:2),mul:EnvGen.kr(Env.perc,Blip.ar([rrand(1,30),rrand(1,30)]))))})};
~strukt4_2_2={Mix.fill(33,{SinOsc.ar(freq:[LFDNoise1,LFDNoise3,LFDNoise0].choose.kr(1,rrand(333,6666),rrand(333,6666))*XLine.kr(rrand(0.125,8),rrand(0.125,8),150,doneAction:2)+666*XLine.kr(rrand(0.125,8),rrand(0.125,8),33,doneAction:2))})};

//strukt5
~strukt5_1={LeakDC.ar(Limiter.ar(ChaosGen.allSubclasses.choose.ar([rrand(1,30),rrand(1,30)]),6))};
//~strukt5_2={LeakDC.ar(Limiter.ar([LFDNoise0,LFDNoise1,LFDNoise3].choose.ar([rrand(1,30),rrand(1,30)])))};

//strukt6
~strukt6_1={LeakDC.ar(Limiter.ar(WhiteNoise.ar(EnvGen.kr(Env.perc,ChaosGen.allSubclasses.choose.ar([rrand(1,30),rrand(1,30)])))))};
~strukt6_2={LeakDC.ar(Limiter.ar(WhiteNoise.ar([LFDNoise0,LFDNoise1,LFDNoise3].choose.ar([rrand(1,30),rrand(1,30)]))))};

//strukt7
~strukt7_1={Pan2.ar(Mix.fill(33,{[SinOsc, Saw, Pulse].choose.ar(freq:rrand(33,2000)*XLine.kr(rrand(0.467,6.66),rrand(0.467,6.66),150,doneAction:2)) })*0.1)};
~strukt7_2={Pan2.ar(Mix.fill(33,{[SinOsc, Saw, Pulse].choose.ar(freq:rrand(666,2222)*XLine.kr(rrand(0.467,6.6),rrand(0.467,6.66),150,doneAction:2)) })*0.1)};
~strukt7_3={Pan2.ar(Mix.fill(33,{[SinOsc, Saw, Pulse].choose.ar(freq:rrand(666,2222)*XLine.kr(rrand(0.467,6.66),rrand(0.467,6.66),150,doneAction:2)) })*0.1)};

//strukt7
~strukt8={Pan2.ar(Blip.ar([rrand(1,30),rrand(1,30)]))};

~piece=Task({

//strukt1 A
~strukt1_1={Mix.fill(33,{[SinOsc, Saw, Pulse].choose.ar(freq:[rrand(33,2000),rrand(33,2000)]*XLine.kr(rrand(0.125,8),rrand(0.125,8),150,doneAction:2)) })*0.06};
~strukt1_2={Mix.fill(33,{[SinOsc, Saw, Pulse].choose.ar(freq:[rrand(666,2222),rrand(666,2222)]*XLine.kr(rrand(0.125,8),rrand(0.125,8),150,doneAction:2)) })*0.06};
~strukt1_3={Mix.fill(33,{[SinOsc, Saw, Pulse].choose.ar(freq:[rrand(666,2222),rrand(666,2222)]*XLine.kr(rrand(0.125,8),rrand(0.125,8),150,doneAction:2)) })*0.06};

//strukt1 B
~strukt1_4={Mix.fill(33,{[SinOsc, Saw, Pulse].choose.ar(freq:[rrand(33,2000),rrand(33,2000)]*XLine.kr(rrand(0.125,8),rrand(0.125,8),150,doneAction:2)*TRand.kr(rrand(0.125,4),rrand(0.125,4),Impulse.kr(1/10)) )*0.06})};
~strukt1_5={Mix.fill(33,{[SinOsc, Saw, Pulse].choose.ar(freq:[rrand(666,2222),rrand(666,2222)]*XLine.kr(rrand(0.125,8),rrand(0.125,8),150,doneAction:2))*TRand.kr(rrand(0.125,4),rrand(0.125,4),Impulse.kr(1/10)) })*0.06};
~strukt1_6={Mix.fill(33,{[SinOsc, Saw, Pulse].choose.ar(freq:[rrand(666,2222),rrand(666,2222)]*XLine.kr(rrand(0.125,8),rrand(0.125,8),150,doneAction:2))*TRand.kr(rrand(0.125,4),rrand(0.125,4),Impulse.kr(1/10)) })*0.06};

//strukt2
~strukt2_1={Mix.fill(33,{FreeVerb.ar([SinOsc, Saw, Pulse].choose.ar(freq:[rrand(33,2000),rrand(33,2000)] * TRand.kr(0.125,4,Impulse.kr(1/10)),mul:EnvGen.kr(Env.perc,Impulse.kr(1/2 * TRand.kr(0.125,4,Impulse.kr(1/5)))*XLine.kr(rrand(0.125,4),rrand(0.125,4),159,doneAction:2)) ))})*0.3};
~strukt2_2={Mix.fill(33,{FreeVerb.ar([SinOsc, Saw, Pulse].choose.ar(freq:[rrand(33,2000),rrand(33,2000)],mul:[0.3,0.3]) )})};

//strukt3
~strukt3={GVerb.ar([SinOsc, Saw, Pulse].choose.ar(freq:322,mul:Blip.ar(rrand(1,30)*TRand.kr(0.125,4,Impulse.kr([1/4,1/7]))*XLine.kr(rrand(0.125,4),rrand(0.125,4),150,doneAction:2))),revtime:0.3)*3};

//strukt4
~strukt4_1_1={GVerb.ar(WhiteNoise.ar(mul:Blip.ar(rrand(1,30)*TRand.kr(0.125,4,Impulse.kr([1/4,1/7]))*XLine.kr(rrand(0.125,4),rrand(0.125,4),159,doneAction:2))),revtime:0.3)*3};
~strukt4_1_2={GVerb.ar(WhiteNoise.ar(mul:ChaosGen.allSubclasses.choose.ar([rrand(1,30),rrand(1,30)]),revtime:0.3)*3)};

//strukt5
~strukt4_2_1={Mix.fill(33,{([Saw,Pulse,SinOsc].choose.ar(freq:[LFDNoise0,LFDNoise1,LFDNoise3].choose.kr(1,505,322)+666*XLine.kr(rrand(0.125,8),rrand(0.125,8),150,doneAction:2),mul:EnvGen.kr(Env.perc,Blip.ar([rrand(1,30),rrand(1,30)]))))})};
~strukt4_2_2={Mix.fill(33,{SinOsc.ar(freq:[LFDNoise1,LFDNoise3,LFDNoise0].choose.kr(1,rrand(333,6666),rrand(333,6666))*XLine.kr(rrand(0.125,8),rrand(0.125,8),150,doneAction:2)+666*XLine.kr(rrand(0.125,8),rrand(0.125,8),33,doneAction:2))})};

//strukt5
~strukt5_1={LeakDC.ar(Limiter.ar(ChaosGen.allSubclasses.choose.ar([rrand(1,30),rrand(1,30)]),6))};
//~strukt5_2={LeakDC.ar(Limiter.ar([LFDNoise0,LFDNoise1,LFDNoise3].choose.ar([rrand(1,30),rrand(1,30)])))};

//strukt6
~strukt6_1={LeakDC.ar(Limiter.ar(WhiteNoise.ar(EnvGen.kr(Env.perc,ChaosGen.allSubclasses.choose.ar([rrand(1,30),rrand(1,30)])))))};
~strukt6_2={LeakDC.ar(Limiter.ar(WhiteNoise.ar([LFDNoise0,LFDNoise1,LFDNoise3].choose.ar([rrand(1,30),rrand(1,30)]))))};

//strukt7
~strukt7_1={Pan2.ar(Mix.fill(33,{[SinOsc, Saw, Pulse].choose.ar(freq:rrand(33,2000)*XLine.kr(rrand(0.467,6.66),rrand(0.467,6.66),150,doneAction:2)) })*0.1)};
~strukt7_2={Pan2.ar(Mix.fill(33,{[SinOsc, Saw, Pulse].choose.ar(freq:rrand(666,2222)*XLine.kr(rrand(0.467,6.6),rrand(0.467,6.66),150,doneAction:2)) })*0.1)};
~strukt7_3={Pan2.ar(Mix.fill(33,{[SinOsc, Saw, Pulse].choose.ar(freq:rrand(666,2222)*XLine.kr(rrand(0.467,6.66),rrand(0.467,6.66),150,doneAction:2)) })*0.1)};

//strukt7
~strukt8={Pan2.ar(Blip.ar([rrand(1,30),rrand(1,30)]))};

    ~sec1=[~strukt1_1,~strukt1_2,~strukt1_3,~strukt1_4,~strukt1_5,~strukt1_6].choose;
    ~sec2=[~strukt2_1,~strukt2_2].choose;
    ~sec3=[~strukt3].choose;
    ~sec4=[~strukt4_2_1,~strukt4_2_1,~strukt4_2_2].choose;
    ~sec5=[~strukt5_1].choose;
    ~sec6=[~strukt6_1,~strukt6_2].choose;
    ~sec7=[~strukt7_1,~strukt7_2,~strukt7_3].choose;
    ~sec8=[~strukt8].choose;

    ~f1=[~sec1,~sec2,~sec3,~sec4,~sec5,~sec7].choose.play; 150.wait; ~f1.free;
    ~f1=[~sec1,~sec2,~sec3,~sec4,~sec5,~sec7].choose.play; 150.wait; ~f1.free;
    ~f1=[~sec1,~sec2,~sec3,~sec4,~sec5,~sec7].choose.play; 150.wait; ~f1.free;

    ~f1=[~sec5,~sec6].choose.play; 75.wait; ~f1.free;

//strukt1 A
~strukt1_1={Mix.fill(33,{[SinOsc, Saw, Pulse].choose.ar(freq:[rrand(33,2000),rrand(33,2000)]*XLine.kr(rrand(0.125,8),rrand(0.125,8),150,doneAction:2)) })*0.06};
~strukt1_2={Mix.fill(33,{[SinOsc, Saw, Pulse].choose.ar(freq:[rrand(666,2222),rrand(666,2222)]*XLine.kr(rrand(0.125,8),rrand(0.125,8),150,doneAction:2)) })*0.06};
~strukt1_3={Mix.fill(33,{[SinOsc, Saw, Pulse].choose.ar(freq:[rrand(666,2222),rrand(666,2222)]*XLine.kr(rrand(0.125,8),rrand(0.125,8),150,doneAction:2)) })*0.06};

//strukt1 B
~strukt1_4={Mix.fill(33,{[SinOsc, Saw, Pulse].choose.ar(freq:[rrand(33,2000),rrand(33,2000)]*XLine.kr(rrand(0.125,8),rrand(0.125,8),150,doneAction:2)*TRand.kr(rrand(0.125,4),rrand(0.125,4),Impulse.kr(1/10)) )*0.06})};
~strukt1_5={Mix.fill(33,{[SinOsc, Saw, Pulse].choose.ar(freq:[rrand(666,2222),rrand(666,2222)]*XLine.kr(rrand(0.125,8),rrand(0.125,8),150,doneAction:2))*TRand.kr(rrand(0.125,4),rrand(0.125,4),Impulse.kr(1/10)) })*0.06};
~strukt1_6={Mix.fill(33,{[SinOsc, Saw, Pulse].choose.ar(freq:[rrand(666,2222),rrand(666,2222)]*XLine.kr(rrand(0.125,8),rrand(0.125,8),150,doneAction:2))*TRand.kr(rrand(0.125,4),rrand(0.125,4),Impulse.kr(1/10)) })*0.06};

//strukt2
~strukt2_1={Mix.fill(33,{FreeVerb.ar([SinOsc, Saw, Pulse].choose.ar(freq:[rrand(33,2000),rrand(33,2000)] * TRand.kr(0.125,4,Impulse.kr(1/10)),mul:EnvGen.kr(Env.perc,Impulse.kr(1/2 * TRand.kr(0.125,4,Impulse.kr(1/5)))*XLine.kr(rrand(0.125,4),rrand(0.125,4),159,doneAction:2)) ))})*0.3};
~strukt2_2={Mix.fill(33,{FreeVerb.ar([SinOsc, Saw, Pulse].choose.ar(freq:[rrand(33,2000),rrand(33,2000)],mul:[0.3,0.3]) )})};

//strukt3
~strukt3={GVerb.ar([SinOsc, Saw, Pulse].choose.ar(freq:322,mul:Blip.ar(rrand(1,30)*TRand.kr(0.125,4,Impulse.kr([1/4,1/7]))*XLine.kr(rrand(0.125,4),rrand(0.125,4),150,doneAction:2))),revtime:0.3)*3};

//strukt4
~strukt4_1_1={GVerb.ar(WhiteNoise.ar(mul:Blip.ar(rrand(1,30)*TRand.kr(0.125,4,Impulse.kr([1/4,1/7]))*XLine.kr(rrand(0.125,4),rrand(0.125,4),159,doneAction:2))),revtime:0.3)*3};
~strukt4_1_2={GVerb.ar(WhiteNoise.ar(mul:ChaosGen.allSubclasses.choose.ar([rrand(1,30),rrand(1,30)]),revtime:0.3)*3)};

//strukt5
~strukt4_2_1={Mix.fill(33,{([Saw,Pulse,SinOsc].choose.ar(freq:[LFDNoise0,LFDNoise1,LFDNoise3].choose.kr(1,505,322)+666*XLine.kr(rrand(0.125,8),rrand(0.125,8),150,doneAction:2),mul:EnvGen.kr(Env.perc,Blip.ar([rrand(1,30),rrand(1,30)]))))})};
~strukt4_2_2={Mix.fill(33,{SinOsc.ar(freq:[LFDNoise1,LFDNoise3,LFDNoise0].choose.kr(1,rrand(333,6666),rrand(333,6666))*XLine.kr(rrand(0.125,8),rrand(0.125,8),150,doneAction:2)+666*XLine.kr(rrand(0.125,8),rrand(0.125,8),33,doneAction:2))})};

//strukt5
~strukt5_1={LeakDC.ar(Limiter.ar(ChaosGen.allSubclasses.choose.ar([rrand(1,30),rrand(1,30)]),6))};
//~strukt5_2={LeakDC.ar(Limiter.ar([LFDNoise0,LFDNoise1,LFDNoise3].choose.ar([rrand(1,30),rrand(1,30)])))};

//strukt6
~strukt6_1={LeakDC.ar(Limiter.ar(WhiteNoise.ar(EnvGen.kr(Env.perc,ChaosGen.allSubclasses.choose.ar([rrand(1,30),rrand(1,30)])))))};
~strukt6_2={LeakDC.ar(Limiter.ar(WhiteNoise.ar([LFDNoise0,LFDNoise1,LFDNoise3].choose.ar([rrand(1,30),rrand(1,30)]))))};

//strukt7
~strukt7_1={Pan2.ar(Mix.fill(33,{[SinOsc, Saw, Pulse].choose.ar(freq:rrand(33,2000)*XLine.kr(rrand(0.467,6.66),rrand(0.467,6.66),150,doneAction:2)) })*0.1)};
~strukt7_2={Pan2.ar(Mix.fill(33,{[SinOsc, Saw, Pulse].choose.ar(freq:rrand(666,2222)*XLine.kr(rrand(0.467,6.6),rrand(0.467,6.66),150,doneAction:2)) })*0.1)};
~strukt7_3={Pan2.ar(Mix.fill(33,{[SinOsc, Saw, Pulse].choose.ar(freq:rrand(666,2222)*XLine.kr(rrand(0.467,6.66),rrand(0.467,6.66),150,doneAction:2)) })*0.1)};

//strukt7
~strukt8={Pan2.ar(Blip.ar([rrand(1,30),rrand(1,30)]))};

    ~sec1=[~strukt1_1,~strukt1_2,~strukt1_3,~strukt1_4,~strukt1_5,~strukt1_6].choose;
    ~sec2=[~strukt2_1,~strukt2_2].choose;
    ~sec3=[~strukt3].choose;
    ~sec4=[~strukt4_2_1,~strukt4_2_1,~strukt4_2_2].choose;
    ~sec5=[~strukt5_1].choose;
    ~sec6=[~strukt6_1,~strukt6_2].choose;
    ~sec7=[~strukt7_1,~strukt7_2,~strukt7_3].choose;
    ~sec8=[~strukt8].choose;

    ~f1=[~sec1,~sec2,~sec3,~sec4,~sec5,~sec7].choose.play; 150.wait; ~f1.free;
    ~f1=[~sec1,~sec2,~sec3,~sec4,~sec5,~sec7].choose.play; 150.wait; ~f1.free;
    ~f1=[~sec1,~sec2,~sec3,~sec4,~sec5,~sec7].choose.play; 150.wait; ~f1.free;

    ~f1=[~sec5,~sec6].choose.play; 75.wait; ~f1.free;


//strukt1 A
~strukt1_1={Mix.fill(33,{[SinOsc, Saw, Pulse].choose.ar(freq:[rrand(33,2000),rrand(33,2000)]*XLine.kr(rrand(0.125,8),rrand(0.125,8),150,doneAction:2)) })*0.06};
~strukt1_2={Mix.fill(33,{[SinOsc, Saw, Pulse].choose.ar(freq:[rrand(666,2222),rrand(666,2222)]*XLine.kr(rrand(0.125,8),rrand(0.125,8),150,doneAction:2)) })*0.06};
~strukt1_3={Mix.fill(33,{[SinOsc, Saw, Pulse].choose.ar(freq:[rrand(666,2222),rrand(666,2222)]*XLine.kr(rrand(0.125,8),rrand(0.125,8),150,doneAction:2)) })*0.06};

//strukt1 B
~strukt1_4={Mix.fill(33,{[SinOsc, Saw, Pulse].choose.ar(freq:[rrand(33,2000),rrand(33,2000)]*XLine.kr(rrand(0.125,8),rrand(0.125,8),150,doneAction:2)*TRand.kr(rrand(0.125,4),rrand(0.125,4),Impulse.kr(1/10)) )*0.06})};
~strukt1_5={Mix.fill(33,{[SinOsc, Saw, Pulse].choose.ar(freq:[rrand(666,2222),rrand(666,2222)]*XLine.kr(rrand(0.125,8),rrand(0.125,8),150,doneAction:2))*TRand.kr(rrand(0.125,4),rrand(0.125,4),Impulse.kr(1/10)) })*0.06};
~strukt1_6={Mix.fill(33,{[SinOsc, Saw, Pulse].choose.ar(freq:[rrand(666,2222),rrand(666,2222)]*XLine.kr(rrand(0.125,8),rrand(0.125,8),150,doneAction:2))*TRand.kr(rrand(0.125,4),rrand(0.125,4),Impulse.kr(1/10)) })*0.06};

//strukt2
~strukt2_1={Mix.fill(33,{FreeVerb.ar([SinOsc, Saw, Pulse].choose.ar(freq:[rrand(33,2000),rrand(33,2000)] * TRand.kr(0.125,4,Impulse.kr(1/10)),mul:EnvGen.kr(Env.perc,Impulse.kr(1/2 * TRand.kr(0.125,4,Impulse.kr(1/5)))*XLine.kr(rrand(0.125,4),rrand(0.125,4),159,doneAction:2)) ))})*0.3};
~strukt2_2={Mix.fill(33,{FreeVerb.ar([SinOsc, Saw, Pulse].choose.ar(freq:[rrand(33,2000),rrand(33,2000)],mul:[0.3,0.3]) )})};

//strukt3
~strukt3={GVerb.ar([SinOsc, Saw, Pulse].choose.ar(freq:322,mul:Blip.ar(rrand(1,30)*TRand.kr(0.125,4,Impulse.kr([1/4,1/7]))*XLine.kr(rrand(0.125,4),rrand(0.125,4),150,doneAction:2))),revtime:0.3)*3};

//strukt4
~strukt4_1_1={GVerb.ar(WhiteNoise.ar(mul:Blip.ar(rrand(1,30)*TRand.kr(0.125,4,Impulse.kr([1/4,1/7]))*XLine.kr(rrand(0.125,4),rrand(0.125,4),159,doneAction:2))),revtime:0.3)*3};
~strukt4_1_2={GVerb.ar(WhiteNoise.ar(mul:ChaosGen.allSubclasses.choose.ar([rrand(1,30),rrand(1,30)]),revtime:0.3)*3)};

//strukt5
~strukt4_2_1={Mix.fill(33,{([Saw,Pulse,SinOsc].choose.ar(freq:[LFDNoise0,LFDNoise1,LFDNoise3].choose.kr(1,505,322)+666*XLine.kr(rrand(0.125,8),rrand(0.125,8),150,doneAction:2),mul:EnvGen.kr(Env.perc,Blip.ar([rrand(1,30),rrand(1,30)]))))})};
~strukt4_2_2={Mix.fill(33,{SinOsc.ar(freq:[LFDNoise1,LFDNoise3,LFDNoise0].choose.kr(1,rrand(333,6666),rrand(333,6666))*XLine.kr(rrand(0.125,8),rrand(0.125,8),150,doneAction:2)+666*XLine.kr(rrand(0.125,8),rrand(0.125,8),33,doneAction:2))})};

//strukt5
~strukt5_1={LeakDC.ar(Limiter.ar(ChaosGen.allSubclasses.choose.ar([rrand(1,30),rrand(1,30)]),6))};
//~strukt5_2={LeakDC.ar(Limiter.ar([LFDNoise0,LFDNoise1,LFDNoise3].choose.ar([rrand(1,30),rrand(1,30)])))};

//strukt6
~strukt6_1={LeakDC.ar(Limiter.ar(WhiteNoise.ar(EnvGen.kr(Env.perc,ChaosGen.allSubclasses.choose.ar([rrand(1,30),rrand(1,30)])))))};
~strukt6_2={LeakDC.ar(Limiter.ar(WhiteNoise.ar([LFDNoise0,LFDNoise1,LFDNoise3].choose.ar([rrand(1,30),rrand(1,30)]))))};

//strukt7
~strukt7_1={Pan2.ar(Mix.fill(33,{[SinOsc, Saw, Pulse].choose.ar(freq:rrand(33,2000)*XLine.kr(rrand(0.467,6.66),rrand(0.467,6.66),150,doneAction:2)) })*0.1)};
~strukt7_2={Pan2.ar(Mix.fill(33,{[SinOsc, Saw, Pulse].choose.ar(freq:rrand(666,2222)*XLine.kr(rrand(0.467,6.6),rrand(0.467,6.66),150,doneAction:2)) })*0.1)};
~strukt7_3={Pan2.ar(Mix.fill(33,{[SinOsc, Saw, Pulse].choose.ar(freq:rrand(666,2222)*XLine.kr(rrand(0.467,6.66),rrand(0.467,6.66),150,doneAction:2)) })*0.1)};

//strukt7
~strukt8={Pan2.ar(Blip.ar([rrand(1,30),rrand(1,30)]))};

    ~sec1=[~strukt1_1,~strukt1_2,~strukt1_3,~strukt1_4,~strukt1_5,~strukt1_6].choose;
    ~sec2=[~strukt2_1,~strukt2_2].choose;
    ~sec3=[~strukt3].choose;
    ~sec4=[~strukt4_2_1,~strukt4_2_1,~strukt4_2_2].choose;
    ~sec5=[~strukt5_1].choose;
    ~sec6=[~strukt6_1,~strukt6_2].choose;
    ~sec7=[~strukt7_1,~strukt7_2,~strukt7_3].choose;
    ~sec8=[~strukt8].choose;

    ~f1=[~sec1,~sec2,~sec3,~sec4,~sec5,~sec7].choose.play; 150.wait; ~f1.free;
    ~f1=[~sec1,~sec2,~sec3,~sec4,~sec5,~sec7].choose.play; 150.wait; ~f1.free;
    ~f1=[~sec1,~sec2,~sec3,~sec4,~sec5,~sec7].choose.play; 150.wait; ~f1.free;

    ~f1=[~sec5,~sec6].choose.play; 75.wait; ~f1.free;
}).play;
)

Server.local.makeWindow;
```

Comment: Ironically, this would be a lot easier to answer is you could simplify your code. Can you provide an example that's got less going on it?

Comment: You could replace a lot of the repetitive code with `for` or `do` loops and some carefully constructed `Array`s IMO